# Symfony2.3 symlink web directory causing login form redirect loop

Tags: symfony, redirect, authentication

My goal is to have URLs like these for these 3 apps:

```
http://somedomain.com/symfony-app/app_dev.php
http://somedomain.com/symfony-app2/app_dev.php
http://somedomain.com/symfony-app3/app_dev.php
```

UPDATE: All 3 sf2 applications are independent of each other. Meaning there are no interaction between them.

Directory structure is like this:

```
/var/webroot/symfony-app 
/var/webroot/symfony-app2 
/var/webroot/symfony-app3
```

(where *symfony-app* is a symlink to the sf web folder of symfony-app placed on some other directory outside of */var/webroot*). Doing the same with symfony-app2 and symfony-app3.

**Problem:** I'm getting redirect loop on http://somedomain.com/symfony-app/app_dev.php/login whenever I access http://somedomain.com/symfony-app/app_dev.php

*security.yml*

```
 security:
       providers:
          fos_userbundle:
             id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

      encoders:
           FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

      firewalls:
          main:
              http_basic: ~
              pattern: ^/
              form_login:
                 provider: fos_userbundle
                 csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
                 default_target_path: /admin #authentication required page
                 always_use_default_target_path: true
              logout:
                 target: /login
              anonymous:    true
              switch_user: true

      access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
```

Getting this error message after setting intercept_redirects: true in config_dev.yml:

This request redirects to http://somedomain.com/symfony-app/app_dev.php/login.
The redirect was intercepted by the web debug toolbar to help debugging. For more information, see the "intercept-redirects" option of the Profiler.

App works well when used on an apache vhost but each on totally different urls. No modifications done on the .htaccess or security.yml when I tried having all 3 apps as a subdirectories.

Did I miss any configuration in the security.yml? .htaccess?

Any help would be appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 0):

On first hint, w/out going into details, it smells like your sessions are getting mixed. Try setting the cookie path config http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#cookie-path

**EDIT** - asked to explain a bit further

Session cookie is generated by PHP when session is started in order to be able to track user in further visits and http requests she makes to your web app. By default, cookie domain is set to the domain the request was made to, "somedomain.com" in your example, and path to /. So, all those 3 web apps will share the same session cookie - somedomain.com with path /. I meant you should set cookie path in all 3 web apps of yours, so they can each have it's own session cookie, as following:

```
# symfony-app/app/config.yml
framework:
    session:
        cookie_path: /symfony-app/

# symfony-app2/app/config.yml
framework:
    session:
        cookie_path: /symfony-app2/

# symfony-app3/app/config.yml
framework:
    session:
        cookie_path: /symfony-app3/
```

That way, each app will have it's own session cookie:

- app1 will have domain somedomain.com and path /symfony-app/
- app2 will have domain somedomain.com and path /symfony-app2/
- app2 will have domain somedomain.com and path /symfony-app3/

and they will not re-use session cookie from the other apps.

Still, not quite sure if that was your problem, but that was first thing I noticed. It might have happen you open app1, and then app2, which got the cookie from app1, but found no session data for that id from the cookie, since it was saved in app1 session storage, and you got yourself in the loop.

Comment: Care to explain a bit further? I've only setup 1 sf application so far and I'm already getting this redirect loop. I haven't added the 2 other applications yet.